# website layout issue(Horizontal scroll bar at the end)

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

My previous theme was working fine but since I changed my theme few days ago I am getting a scroll bar at the end of every page. Can someone tell me , from where I can fix this and adjust the width of the page? I am attaching a screenshot also
[image]

Answer (score 1):

One or more elements on your page have a fixed width, which is wider than your browsers window. I can see that your 2nd Navi Bar (Free shipping ..) is cut off, so I presume it is of fixed width or non-responsive.

Can you provide a link?

---

**EDIT:**

Your theme is not responsive, but it is a fixed width of width: 1170px - as defined in your body tags css - see the last line.

So any browser window smaller than 1170px will have horizontal scrollbars.

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888888;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.55;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 25px;
    width: 1170px;
}
```

You are trying to include a responsive css file, which can not be found. Are you sure it is on the server?

http://www.blog.zumastic.com/running-test-work/skin/frontend/rwd/galamrhandsome_blue/css/responsive1.css

[image]

Comment: www.blog.zumastic.com/running-test-work/

Comment: I've just also seen in the console that you are trying to include a responsive.css, which is not found: http://www.blog.zumastic.com/running-test-work/skin/frontend/rwd/galamrhandsome_blue/css/responsive1.css

Comment: That was my previous theme "galamrhandsome" and I am not trying to include it anywhere. The current theme name is "eclipse" but it didn't fall in default category. It falls in rwd when I checked in cpanel so my current package name is "rwd" and default is "eclipse" in system-configuration-design tab

Comment: Could this be a caching issue then - have you disabled cache and cleared the var/cache folder?

Comment: I've just did as you said but still its same and its a resposive theme, here's the demo http://demo.magikthemes.com/index.php/eclipseblue/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22731/discussion-between-tecjam-and-lucky-dhillon).